# Can i use C++ when compiling an app for the ipod?

Tags: compiler-construction, ipod

From what i hear ipod requires objective C but you can get away with doing almost(?) everything in C.

I would like to know can i program everything i need in C++ (which wouldnt touch ipod libs) then have the little C and obj C code required to run? or is it impossible to use C++ on the ipod?(due to runtime or whatever reason)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with [Dragon Fly SDK](http://www.dragonfiresdk.com/index.htm).

If you want something free, you have to write some binder in objective c and call them from c++ code..

If you just need a few c++ libraries, try [cross-compiling](http://iphone.olipion.com/cross-compilation).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can mix Objective-C and C++ to develop an iOS application. Know the [limitation limitations](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html) however.

SDL 1.3 with iOS support provides an example of what you are asking for. The core code is written in C while Objective-C is used to implements platform specific functionality.